# Drupal 6: using too many Views module causing site to go down cos of too many mysql connection

Tags: mysql, database, drupal, drupal-6, performance

I have [HostGator Baby Shared Plan](http://www.hostgator.com/shared.shtml) . I develop Drupal site on. everything was fine at the beginning, then by the time i go further with development, site started ti work really slow. now it is not working at all. giving my sql errors like TOO many connections, etc...

I created so many blocks, pages with View. so it makes my site to so much depend on database. should not I do that? can it be the reason of my site's no working now.

appreciate helps!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Drupal uses a lot of Database. However, you can cache the results of most Views (check the main screen of each view to enable it) and also there's an option to cache the blocks. It all depends in the content of your views and if users are mostly registered or anonymous.

You can also use modules like Boost which saves static html pages so for anoymous visits your database is not touched at all (just the first time, as the page needs to be generated someday...).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use HostGator. If you're looking for something in the same price range, try DreamHost -- they officially support Drupal on their hosting plans.

Ferran's answer is fine once you're done developing, but you shouldn't devlop with cache turned on or else you won't be able to see your own changes.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check the Views filters, not fetching to many rows at a time (for example fetching a week back for the front page).